# Update a JSON Object Value When onClick in React

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs

I've been following a tutorial about update a value, it `increments` the value when the user clicks a button.

But, I have the `JSON` object value to be updated. The value should be updated when the user clicks a button and `vice versa`. After I tried to implements following the example, it not changed. Here's my code:

**1. onClick:**

```
<div>
  Point: {item.point}&emsp;
  <button onClick={() => setCount(item.point + 1)} class="btn"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></button>
  <button onClick={() => setCount(item.point - 1)} class="btn"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
</div>
```

**2. useState:**

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

**3. comments.json:**

```
{
        "id": "fa1ca3c1-cc1e-4ed9-86b8-f60d8312d499",
        "author": "Neal Topham",
        "avatar": "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/1/",
        "date": "2017-02-08T00:30:05.552Z",
        "message": "Mungkin ada fenomena paranormal yang tidak bisa dijelaskan. Lebih baik nyala mati sendiri daripada tidak nyala sama sekali",
        "point": 3,
}
```

**4. Tutorial Link:**

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. useState:**

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
```

**2. Modified Button:**

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
   // first, clone it
    const newItems = [...items];
    newItems[idx] = {
      ...item,
      point: item.point + 1
    };
    setItems(newItems);
  }}
  className="btn-upvote"
>
  <i className="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
</button>

 <button
  onClick={() => {
    // first, clone it
    const newItems = [...items];
    newItems[idx] = {
      ...item,
      point: item.point - 1
    };
    setItems(newItems);
  }}
  className="btn-downvote"
>
  <i className="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will probably need your object to live in your state in your case.

useState

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState({
  "id": "fa1ca3c1-cc1e-4ed9-86b8-f60d8312d499",
  "author": "Neal Topham",
  "avatar": "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/1/",
  "date": "2017-02-08T00:30:05.552Z",
  "message": "Mungkin ada fenomena paranormal ...",
  "point": 3,
});
```

You cannot mutate part of the state, so you will basically make a modified copy of it.

```
const addCount = (n) => {
  setMessage({
    ...message,
    point: message.point + n
  });
};
```

```
<div>
  Point: {message.point}&emsp;
  <button onClick={() => addCount(1)} class="btn"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></button>
  <button onClick={() => addCount(-1)} class="btn"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: The JSON object is in comments.json file

Comment: I'm new to react. Your answer is very clear. "...message" gives the JSON current object and then added "point" element replace its point element. That's what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `count` instead of `item.point`.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(item.point);
```

```
<div>
  Point: {count}&emsp;
  <button onClick={() => setCount(item.point + 1)} class="btn"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></button>
  <button onClick={() => setCount(item.point - 1)} class="btn"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your onClick listeners update the `count` variable while you're rendering `item.point`.

At this point React simply renders the `point` property of the `item` object, which is not bound to any change of the `count` state variable.

Depending on your application logic you might want to extract the `item.point` directly into `count` variable like this:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(item.point);
```

and render `{count}` instead of `{item.point}`

However this approach will work only in one direction, meaning that when you click on the button the rendered value will change, but it will not update the actual `point` property of the `item` object